# Merge 2 AsyncThrowingStream while keeping sorting

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency, task, asyncstream

## Context

I have 2 `AsyncThrowingStream(s)` which push (respectively) the first 5 even (and odd) non negative integers.

```
var evens = stream(start: 0) // 0, 2, 4, 6, 8
var odds = stream(start: 1) // 1, 3, 5, 7, 9
```

Every value is pushed after `1...3` seconds.

## Concurrency

Since the 2 streams need some time to push the next value, I want to run them in concurrency.

E.g.

```
Task {
    let evens = stream(start: 0)
    for try await even in evens {
        
    }
}
Task {
    let odds = stream(start: 1)
    for try await odd in odds {
        
    }
}
```

## Processing in order

Next, I have this function

```
func process(value: Int) {
    print(value)
}
```

## Question

How can I invoke `process(value:)` for all the generated `Int(s)` in order?

The result invocations should look like this

```
process(value: 0)
process(value: 1)
process(value: 2)
process(value: 3)
process(value: 4)
process(value: 5)
process(value: 6)
process(value: 7)
process(value: 8)
process(value: 9)
```

## More

For reference and testing I am adding a mock implementation to generate the 2 streams

```
func stream(start: Int) -> AsyncThrowingStream<Int, Error> {
    .init { continuation in
        Task {
            for index in stride(from: start, to: 10, by: 2) {
                continuation.yield(index)
                let random = UInt64.random(in: (1...3))
                try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: random * 1_000_000_000)
            }
            continuation.finish()
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

## Update 1: Example for sync context

To be clear, if this was a sync context, my solution would look like this

```
let evens = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
let odds = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
zip(evens, odds)
    .map { [$0, $1] }
    .flatMap { $0 }
    .forEach(process)

Output:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

## Update 2: Priority Queue

Another requirement that may not be obvious from the question is that `process(value:)` must be called **as soon as** <s>the next integer is produced by the streams.</s> the successor of the last `processed` integer is produced by any of the 2 streams.

In other words:

1. `process(value:)` must be called with arguments following the natural order of the non negative integers `(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)`.
2. AND `process(value:)` must be called as soon as possible (as the next integer has been produced by any of the streams).

Example

```
evens pushes 0
then process(value:0) is called

odds pushed 1
then process(value:1) is called

odds pushed 3
then 3 is put on hold

evens pushes 2
then process(value:2) is called
and process(value:3) is called
```

A Priority Queue sounds like a good fit for this case, but I am looking for the correct implementation compatible with AsyncThrowingStream and Swift Concurrency.

Comment: "I want to run them in concurrency" But that is not precisely what you're doing; if you really want that, shouldn't you be using a task group? There are big differences between two separate tasks and a single task group.

Comment: And what if one of the streams emits two values before the other has a chance to emit one? I mean, how do you _know_ that 1,2,3,4 is the right result? It could be 1,3,2,4, couldn't it?

Comment: Hi @matt, thank your for your comments. Any solution that involves `TaskGroup` is welcome.

Comment: `I mean, how do you know that 1,2,3,4 is the right result? It could be 1,3,2,4, couldn't it?`. I need to call `process(value:)` following the natural sort order of the integers so it must be `0, 1, 2, 3...` regardless of the _speed_ of the 2 streams.

Comment: Added paragraph `Update 1: Example for sync context` to make the question clearer.

Comment: It sounds to me like you'll have to buffer, no?

Comment: @matt I agree. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a good solution compatible with `AsyncThrowingStream` and Swift Concurrency.

Comment: What you're describing is almost AsyncChannel, isn't it? i.e. a stream that responds to back pressure.

Comment: @matt Interesting, I'll look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a broader observation, you can [`zip`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Zip.md) or [`merge`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Merge.md) sequences using Apple’s [Swift Async Algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms) package. For example, you said:

> To be clear, if this was a sync context, my solution would look like this
>
> ```
> let evens = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
> let odds = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
> zip(evens, odds)
>     .map { [$0, $1] }
>     .flatMap { $0 }
>     .forEach(process)
> ```

If you use Apple’s Swift Async Algorithms package, you can (a) make your async sequences by just adding `async`; and (b) [`zip`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Zip.md) the two sequences into one. E.g.:

```swift
let evens = stream(start: 0) // or [0, 2, 4, 6, 8].async
let odds = stream(start: 1)  // or [1, 3, 5, 7, 9].async

for try await (even, odd) in zip(evens, odds) {
    process(value: even)
    process(value: odd)
}
```

This will, for example, not process the third odd element until both the third even and odd elements were emitted.

So, imagine that these two sequences emitted the values in this order: `[0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 7, 4, 9, 6, 8]`. The `zip` approach will process them in order, `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.

---

On the other hand, if you wanted to process them as they come in, you might use [`merge`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Merge.md)

```swift
let evens = stream(start: 0)
let odds = stream(start: 1)

for try await element in merge(evens, odds) {
    process(value: element)
}
```

Considering the above example, this `merge` rendition will process them in the order that they were encountered, e.g., `[0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 7, 4, 9, 6, 8]`.

---

To illustrate the difference between `zip` and `merge`, let me share some RxMarbles-like diagrams, which visually demonstrate these two sequence combining functions. In each diagram, the top two arrows are the timeline for the respective two input sequences, and the bottom arrow is the timeline for the resulting output sequence.

E.g., `zip`:

[image: zip marbles]

As opposed to `merge`:

[image: merge marbles]

Hopefully, that helps illustrate what is going on.

Comment: Yes I wanted to process the values following the natural order or the integers. Updated my question to improve clarity.
Zip is great, no idea it was available for streams. thanks.
The only tiny issue I see with `zip` is that it blocks the _faster_ streams from generating new values until the slower stream catches up. So performance wise, it could lead to suboptimal processing speed. But I am accepting the answer since it definitely solves the issue.

Comment: It doesn’t “block” the faster stream, but rather the stream will buffer the values. But I hear you. I don’t `zip` very much, but rather find `merge` more useful (to process them as they come in). But I thought you explicitly asked to put the faster stream “on hold”, which is why I refactored my answer to lead with `zip`. FWIW, `AsyncThrowingStream` supports a variety of [buffering policies](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/asyncthrowingstream/continuation/bufferingpolicy).

Comment: `It doesn’t “block” the faster stream, but rather the stream will buffer the values.` Well, then this is __exactly__ what I was looking for. Thanks.